# Is there a way to select two counts with different subqueries in one syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically I want to get two counts. The first count is the number of records. The second count is the number of records with data. The two counts are coming from the table called investigation which doesn't have all the state name. So I join it with the other table UsState to get all the state names. I put together the syntax but I am getting an error.

```
SELECT
Name as State,
count (*)from NamrsFrozen2017.Investigation2017 where FiscalYear = 2017 AND StateName in (SELECT distinct StateName FROM [NamrsFrozen2017].[Investigation2017] WHERE (not ReportDate = '' ))[Report Date Records],
count (*) from NamrsFrozen2017.Investigation2017 WHERE FiscalYear = 2017 AND ReportDate != '' AND StateName in (SELECT distinct StateName FROM [NamrsFrozen2017].[Investigation2017] WHERE (not ReportDate = '' ))[Report Date Records with Data]
From
(SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM NamrsFullDw.UsState) s
LEFT JOIN NamrsFrozen2017.Investigation2017 c ON s.Name = c.StateName AND  c.FiscalYear = 2017
  GROUP BY Name
  Order by Name
```

Comment: Instead of using `COUNT(*)` put the column's name in the parenthesis for one of the function. Aggregate functions don't include `NULL` values. `SELECT COUNT(*),COUNT(I) FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(NULL))V(I);` returns 3 and 2 respectively.

Comment: I don't think I understand your response can you clarify. I am getting an error on Name and s     @Larnu

Comment: Well you can't do `SELECT Name, COUNT(*) FROM... AS {alias}, COUNT(*) FROM...`, that doesn't make sense. We can't see what you see so please post some sample data and expected results (as `text`, not an image).

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some correlated sub-queries would help you.  They look like in-line selects but use references to tables outside of the in-line query. Like this:

```
SELECT 
   Name as State,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM NamrsFrozen2017.Investigation2017 
    --I would think you want to view count of records for the current state, and not ALL states
    -- and not ALL states. So filter like this:
    WHERE FiscalYear = 2017 AND StateName = s.Name -- <-Correlated
    --Don't need a full list, like you had before
    -- (SELECT distinct StateName FROM [NamrsFrozen2017].[Investigation2017] WHERE (not ReportDate = '' ))
   ) AS [Report Date Records],
   (SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM NamrsFrozen2017.Investigation2017 
    WHERE FiscalYear = 2017 AND StateName = s.Name -- <- correlated
        AND ReportDate != '' --or maybe ReportDate IS NOT NULL            
    --Don't need to query the full table after correlating this to your FROM clause
    --  in (SELECT distinct StateName FROM [NamrsFrozen2017].[Investigation2017] WHERE (not ReportDate = '' ))
   ) AS [Report Date Records with Data]
FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM NamrsFullDw.UsState) s
   LEFT JOIN NamrsFrozen2017.Investigation2017 c 
        ON s.Name = c.StateName AND c.FiscalYear = 2017
GROUP BY s.Name
ORDER BY s.Name
```

This could probably be optimized much more, but I'm not familiar with your data, or clear on what exactly you are trying to accomplish with your original query.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

The syntax error you're getting is because your inline sub-queries are formatted incorrectly. You can't start with the `COUNT(*)` function; they each need to be fully formed `SELECT` statements. Then each of those needs to be wrapped in parenthesis.

This is what your query should look like.

```
SELECT
  Name AS State
 ,(
    SELECT
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      NamrsFrozen2017.Investigation2017
    WHERE
      FiscalYear = 2017
      AND StateName IN
          (
            SELECT DISTINCT StateName
            FROM NamrsFrozen2017.Investigation2017
            WHERE ReportDate <> ''
          )
  ) AS [Report Date Records]
 ,(
    SELECT
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      NamrsFrozen2017.Investigation2017
    WHERE
      FiscalYear = 2017
      AND ReportDate != ''
      AND StateName IN
          (
            SELECT DISTINCT StateName
            FROM NamrsFrozen2017.Investigation2017
            WHERE (NOT ReportDate = '')
          )
  ) AS [Report Date Records with Data]
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM NamrsFullDw.UsState) AS s
LEFT JOIN
  NamrsFrozen2017.Investigation2017 AS c
    ON
    s.Name = c.StateName
      AND c.FiscalYear = 2017
GROUP BY
  Name
ORDER BY
  Name;
```

There's a secondary question here, which is whether or not this query will do what you're expecting it to do, though. To Larnu's point in the comments, aggregate functions handle `NULL` differently in different circumstances. But without sample data to test against, I  can't tell whether this functioning version of the query will return what you want it to.